# finding probability mass function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

I need help with part (i)

I can see that the number of head form geometric distribution.

Let Y be the number of heads. Then $P(Y=k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p $ .

So the winner will get $10k$ pounds.

Then what would the probability mass function of amounts U for first prize be? I think I'm confused with what 'probability mass function' is.

Thanks.

Sorry. mistake fixed.

Comment: pmf is another way of say probability distribution, so you seem to be on the right way: the support for $Y$ is the set ${10,20, \ldots}$

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you please give me some more hints? I don't know how to write down the distribution...

Answer (score 0):

For (i) you have already done almost all the work: $P(U=10k) = P(Y_1=k) =  (1-p)^{k-1} p$, where $k$ ranges over the positive integers

Similarly $P(V=5k) = P(Y_2=k) = (1-p)^{k-1} p$

Comment: Aha. That's how to write it down! Thanks